# Unable to Deploy or Retrieve source from any ORG

Tags: sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode, sfdx-error

I'm facing an issue while trying to retrieve source code from a package.xml file within our organization. This problem has persisted since last year, despite my attempts to resolve it by both downgrading and updating the versions of my extensions

ERROR:
Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

This is my
Visual Code Studio:

- Version: 1.82.3 (user setup)
- Node.js: 18.15.0 V8:
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

SFDX:
sfdx-cli/7.209.6 win32-x64

Salesforce CLI Integration: v58.15.0

Comment: As was suggested in your previous iteration of this question, seeing the exact command that you're trying to run here would be helpful. Seeing the `sfdx-project.json` file might also help. Also, is your `package.xml` file in the same folder (or a subfolder) as the folder in which you're running this command from? Is the folder you're running this in part of an SFDX project?

Comment: Thanks, Derek, I will have a look at how the project was auto-builded by SFDX. As I will check those folders. It is weird cause, should it be automatically when you create a new standard project using SFDX. It was working a time ago but suddenly it started to through that error, I read another person's solver by downgrading the sf-cli version, but also I read it was fixed. So I don't know if it is VC, Windows, or VC SFDX Extensions.

Comment: Again, you should [edit] your question to show us the sfdx command that you're using.